# How to get the stream from the IP WebCam Android app in Java

Tags: java, mjpeg

I try to make a Java program which can get images from a smartphone. I succeeded to connect to the webserver of the app with an URLConnection and to get some data but the problem is that when I write images to a file, the file seems corrupted when I open it with a program. I've seen that the data is in the MJPEG format, do I need to decode it with something or is this just a problem with the data retrieving ?

Here's my code :

```
package fr.paragoumba.streamingdisplay;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test mp = new Test("http://192.168.1.19:8080/video", null, null);
    }

    public Test(String mjpeg_url, String username, String password)
    {
        int imageCount = 0;

        try {
            if (username != null && password != null)
            {
                Authenticator.setDefault(new HTTPAuthenticator(username, password));
            }

            File file = new File("D:/Desktop/Dev/Out/images/image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            boolean firstImage = true;

            if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();

            URL url = new URL(mjpeg_url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            int lineCount = 0;
            boolean lineCountStart = false;
            boolean saveImage = false;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                //File image = new File("D:/Desktop/Dev/Out/images/image" + imageCount + ".jpeg");

                // Should be checking just for "--" probably
                if (inputLine.lastIndexOf("--Ba4oTvQMY8ew04N8dcnM") > -1)
                {
                    // Got an image boundary, stop last image
                    // Start counting lines to get past:
                    // Content-Type: image/jpeg
                    // Content-Length: 22517

                    saveImage = false;
                    lineCountStart = true;

                    System.out.println("Got a new boundary");
                    System.out.println(inputLine);

                    if (!firstImage) System.exit(0);
                }
                else if (lineCountStart)
                {
                    lineCount++;
                    if (lineCount >= 2)
                    {
                        lineCount = 0;
                        lineCountStart = false;
                        imageCount++;
                        saveImage = true;
                        System.out.println("Starting a new image");

                        firstImage = !firstImage;

                        //if (!image.exists()) image.createNewFile();
                    }
                }
                else if (saveImage)
                {
                    System.out.println("Saving an image line: " + inputLine);

                    /*try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)){

                        pw.print(inputLine);

                    }*/

                    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)){
                        fos.write(inputLine.getBytes());
                    }

                }
                else {

                    System.out.println("What's this:");
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    static class HTTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        private String username, password;

        public HTTPAuthenticator(String user, String pass) {
            username = user;
            password = pass;
        }

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            System.out.println("Requesting Host  : " + getRequestingHost());
            System.out.println("Requesting Port  : " + getRequestingPort());
            System.out.println("Requesting Prompt : " + getRequestingPrompt());
            System.out.println("Requesting Protocol: " + getRequestingProtocol());
            System.out.println("Requesting Scheme : " + getRequestingScheme());
            System.out.println("Requesting Site  : " + getRequestingSite());
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you connect to it with VLC?

Comment: Yes it works with VLC